# JSON File config adding space after :

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am editing a json file in vs code, I have gone and formatted the document but it has added white space after each colon, this space doesn't agree with my code and I would like to change it back to no white space
it currently looks like this:

`{ "input" : "someString"}`

but I need it to look like this:
`{ "input":"someString"}`

Comment: If it is really JSON, you don't need it like you think you do (i.e. VS Code knows JSON pretty well and understands how it can be formatted).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install eslint and configure it, it will do the trick for you.